# Текущее время в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, время

Надо выводить текущее время на экран, чтобы оно менялось в реальном времени. Единственный способ реализации, который я вижу — реализация через таймер. Конечно можно для этого также добавить свойство и реализацию `INotifyPropertyChanged`, но это никак не отменят того факта, что в недрах всё равно будет использоваться таймер. Есть ли варианты получше?

Comment: Как-то все равно надо получать события о том, что время изменилось, так что таймер — нормальный вариант. Только желательно брать таймер, который не привязан к GUI и работает независимо от него (например из `System.Timers`)

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a813d92b-3d15-4f10-9984-5381517157d4/how-to-display-and-update-time-in-wpf-application?forum=wpf

Comment: @АндрейNOP `желательно брать таймер, который не привязан к GUI` - почему?

Comment: @tym32167, чтобы не пропускались секунды же (хотя, они все равно могут пропускаться, но реже)

Comment: @АндрейNOP я к тому, что секунды могут пропускаться, если UI поток занят и не отрабатывает хандлер таймера. Но, по сути, если UI поток занят, то и даже в случае нормального таймера обнова на UI дойдет не сразу - то есть та же проблема по сути :)

Comment: @tym32167, не совсем, с DispatcherTimer проблема усугубится тем, что он начинает отсчет для следующего срабатывания только как фактически сработает предыдущее. Хотя, может, вы и правы.

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну то есть если задать секунду, то обнова будет происходит не чаще, чем раз в секунду. Возможно реже, если UI занят. Что, собственно, лучше, чем пихать задачи раз в секунду зафриженному UI потоку с человеческого таймера :)

Comment: @tym32167, ну да, уже подумал об этом. В любом случае, надо задавать таймеру интервал не ровно 1 с, а некоторую долю от нее, например 0,25 с или типа того